# Using tuples as dict keys and updating value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

```
nodes_g = {}    
with open("calls.txt") as fp3:
    for line in fp3:
        rows3 = line.split(";")
        x, node1, node2, sec, y = line.split(";")
        if node1 not in nodes_g:
            nodes_g[node1, node2] = int(rows3[3])
        elif node1 in nodes_g and node2 in nodes_g:
            nodes_g[node1, node2] += int(rows3[3])

    print(nodes_g)
```

I have this right now, where node1 is calling number and node2 is receiving number and sec or rows3[3] is the amount of seconds that the two numbers talked between themselves. I would like to update the value (seconds of talking) of the dict using the third row of the file, however instead of updating it it just replaces it with the next row 3 value and so on.

link to calls.txt file: http://pastebin.com/RSMnXDtq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because using `nodes_g[node1,node2]` implicitly converts the key to be a tuple `(node1, node2)`. Said so, the conditional check `node1 not in nodes_g` is always false as you are storing tuples, or pairs, as keys and not single nodes.

You should do the following instead:

```
from collections import Counter

nodes_g = Counter()

with open("test.txt") as fp3:
    for line in fp3:
        x, node1, node2, sec, y = line.split(";")
        # Missing keys default to 0.
        nodes_g[node1, node2] += int(sec)

print(nodes_g)
```

Comment: How can I do it so that if say #1 and #2 called and talked for 20 sec and then later #1 and #2 called again and talked for 30 sec; so that it will become like this: {('#1','#2') : 50} ? Because it seems to me this doesn't account for every possibility between say #1 and the other numbers out there. Also, storing the tuple pair as keys is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @no_sleep if in your file, `#1` talked to `#2` for 10 seconds, and later on for 20 seconds, and even later `#2` talked to `#1` for 10 seconds, then the result would be `{(#1, #2): 30, (#2, #1): 10}`. If you want to sum both cases into a single one, use the `frozenset` collections as keys: `nodes_g[frozenset([node1, node2])] += int(sec)`.

Comment: it says frozenset expects at most one argument and I am giving it two.

Comment: @no_sleep you need to pass it an iterable, e.g. a `list`. That's what I've done in the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for that! It works! Also, is there any way that instead of using the numbers in the tuple i can assign just an int instead? like say #1=(some phone number); I want it to be #1=1

Comment: @no_sleep open a new question asking this. I suppose you mean assigning increasing numbers from 0 for each unique phone number, and use that id later on.